# Keycloak: "Account Already Exists" dialog displayed intermittently when I attempt to log in for the first time

Tags: keycloak

I'm seeing a strange scenario in Keycloak:

- Configure Keycloak as an Identity Broker.  It talks to one Identity Provider
- Log in as a user from the Identity Provider
- Occasionally (maybe 1 in every 20 tries), a "Account Already Exists" dialog is displayed.  I have never logged in as this user before.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?  Keycloak version 5.0.0.

Stack trace that is reported when this happens is:

```
keycloak_1       | 2019-05-07 20:57:06,598 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] [cid: 9d4851670ce44e17a39a8910c2a3f24d] (default task-13) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not found in database
keycloak_1       |  at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter.getDelegateForUpdate(UserAdapter.java:67)
keycloak_1       |  at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter.setSingleAttribute(UserAdapter.java:136)
keycloak_1       |  at org.keycloak.broker.provider.HardcodedAttributeMapper.updateBrokeredUser(HardcodedAttributeMapper.java:97)
keycloak_1       |  at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.updateFederatedIdentity(IdentityBrokerService.java:968)
keycloak_1       |  at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.authenticated(IdentityBrokerService.java:578)
keycloak_1       |  at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:432)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We traced the issue to a network latency problem between Keycloak and our MySQL instance.  We observed database connectivity problems and Liquibase schema generation when starting up Keycloak.

The theory on why we saw this particular issue:

- At time t=0, user attempts to log in via identity provider.  The login is successful and the user is then redirected to the Keycloak `/endpoint` endpoint.
- At t=30, the user gets irritated with how long it's taking to log in, and attempts to log in again.  The user logs in successfully again to the identity provider and is then redirected to the Keycloak `/endpoint` endpoint.
- At t=50, the initial login sequence inserts the user supplied via the identity provider into the Keycloak database.
- At t=70, the second login sequence attempts to insert the user, but fails with a constraint violation (`Duplicate user`) because the user was already inserted.  This results in a redirect to the `first-browser-login` page which shows the "Account Already Exists" dialog.